# How to get the user meta data for a post?

Tags: posts, author

Im trying to get the user meta data from a post but only getting the one user:

```
$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 10,
    'offset' => 0,
    'category' => 0,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true
  );

  $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );

foreach ($recent_posts as $post) {
 $user_id = get_the_author_meta('ID', true) // is this correct
 // Is there a function that I need to pass the post ID ($post["ID"])?
 var_dump($user_id);
}
```

When another user makes a post, I cant get their meta data. How, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the post's author as an argument to `get_the_author_meta`:

```
get_the_author_meta('ID', $post->post_author);
```

The second argument is the user's ID. This is stored in the post object in your loop, which you can access it by using `$post->post_author`.

### Reason

The reason behind the current code of yours that isn't working is this piece of code that is included in the `get_the_author_meta()`:

```
if ( ! $user_id ) {
    global $authordata;
    $user_id = isset( $authordata->ID ) ? $authordata->ID : 0;
} else {
    $authordata = get_userdata( $user_id );
}
```

If you set the second argument to true ( which is the `$user_id` ), it will trigger the `else`, and by triggering the else you are passing a `true` to the `get_userdata()`, which will obviously won't work.

Take a look at [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/) page of code reference for more details.